# How to design the server side data structure of autocomplete function?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, string-matching, trie

I have millions of Search Engine Queries looks like this:

```
Stack Overflow
Java Video Tutorials
Cars
C++ vs Java
```

Now i want to implement a auto-complete function could fit these demands:

```
1. Type in 'so',       Prompt ['Stack Overflow','...','...']
2. Type in 'overflow', Prompt ['Stack Overflow','...']
3. Type in 'jvt',      Prompt ['Java Video Tutorials','...']
...
```

Here is my solution:

1). Extract the query's abbreviation, e.g. Stack Overflow -> SO;

2). Split the query into suffix words, e.g. Stack Overflow -> 'Overflow' + 'Stack Overflow';

3). Now we get three sequences for 'Stack Overflow':

```
'SO','Overflow','Stack Overflow'
```

4). In the last, i index these three sequences into a TrieTree, and in the last node of every sequence denote their orignal query(or query id):

```
'o' --> 'Stack Overflow'
'w' --> 'Stack Overflow'
'w' --> 'Stack Overflow'
```

But i think this is too much complexity, is there anyone has a better solution ?  Thanks so much !

Comment: how do you know so = stack overflow, not say 'system overload'?  this algorithm is a bit more complicated that what you are proposing.

Comment: @Randy I mean the prompting shows a list contains 'stack overflow', the list could alose contains 'system overload'.:D thanks !

Comment: Any particular reason why you're building this yourself as opposed to levering something like Lucene to do your dirty work? (adding a token filter that turns `"Stack Overflow"` into `["Stack Overflow", "SO", "Overflow"]` should not be too hard)